# How to merge 2 files that 1 of the files has substring from the other file and print the whole line of the first match

Tags: bash

I have 2 files, the first file include substrings from the second file like this:

```
file1.txt                       file2.txt
---------                       ---------
foo                             bla bla bla
te                              foo foo
bla                             some
                                test
                                foo foo
                                bla bla bla
```

I'm looking for the next result:

```
result.txt
----------
foo foo
test
bla bla bla
```

It should be the order of file 1 and the whole line from file 2 without duplications

In file 1 there are no duplications

I tried next script:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
grep "$line" file2.txt | head -1 >> result.txt                               
done < file1.txt
```

But it stuck and doesn't works well

I am looking at for files with a lot of lines.

I don't care to change it to other commands like awk or sed if anyone knows.

**I am sure there is a faster way to do that**

Thanks all for your help

Comment: If file2.txt contains these two lines, `bla bla` and `bla bla bla`, should be both lines printed, given that `bla` is one of the lines in file1?

Comment: Can you clarify "stuck" ?. With the example you provided the result.txt file is create with no issue.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using GNU grep, try

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    grep -F -m1 "$line" file2.txt                          
done < file1.txt > result.txt
```

`-m N` tells (GNU) grep to stop after N matching lines, so you don't need the `head`. And moving the output redirection outside the loop is more efficient.

Comment: It's stuck after a few lines.
Maybe is there another way to resolve it?